# data validation list matching 2 criteria

Tags: excel

I have 2 tables: one for data entry and another on a different worksheet for lookups. The "DataTbl" has the following columns with no data: [Region] [Employee Name] [Supervisor Name], and the "LookupTbl" has the following columns: [Region] [Employee] [Title] [Supervisor?] with data entered.
The LookupTbl[Region] column lists whole numbers 0-15 and is sorted smallest to largest, with corresponding employee names that are alpha sorted within each region number, followed by their title and either a "Y" or an "N" in the LookupTbl[Supervisor?] column, (this last column contains an IF formula that returns either a "Y" or an "N" based on the entry in Lookup[Title]).

The DataTbl[Region] has validation restricted to whole number (0-15), and based on the input number, will generate a drop down list of the employees in the DataTbl[Employee Name] column field.

What is proving rather difficult is the DataTbl[Supervisor Name] data validation, that I 'd like to generate a drop down list of employee names from the LookupTbl where there is a match for both the Region # and if the corresponding LookupTbl[Supervisor?] is "Y".

As I build the workbook, I may create a user "Menu" sheet where the end user will select a "default" Region Number in a single cell (again, 0-15), for the Supervisor region on the data table... so instead of relying on the Region number input into DataTbl[Region], it will look at the cell for the default Region Number, for Example, let's say Menu!$C$5.

VBA is not an option as it's for use on Excel Online. The LookupTbl will change weekly (and will be manually re-sorted) as folks get hired, fired, promoted, demoted, resign, etc., FYI.

Comment: For what it's worth, you've completely stumped me. I've dug through arrays, fancy INDEX(MATCH), and every other weird thing I can think of. I can provide you the links to what got me something that almost looked like it would work.

Comment: Go for it. I did find [this previous post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19730067/excel-how-to-create-dynamic-data-validation-list-based-on-data-table), but I think it's even more complicated than mine and dumbing it down to my scenario is going to take me some time...

Comment: [This](http://www.excel-university.com/create-depdendent-drop-downs-conditional-data-validation/) is the best I found, but it's been hurting my brain. This [one uses matrixs'](https://fiveminutelessons.com/learn-microsoft-excel/use-index-lookup-multiple-values-list) but I'm not sure that's what you need. I'm really curious if this can be done.

Comment: That post seems to have the same issue I keep running into, that the data isn't really comparing parts of a table. I can't really find anything that looks at column A, then column B, then return the value.

Comment: I'm looking at some solutions by adding a helper column in the Lookup table that returns the region number of the Supervisor is Y and a blank if N.... now working on an INDEX/MATCH validation formula to pull the employee names from that helper column... appreciate your comments!